# probability and random sample

Tags: probability

suppose that a body mass index for a population of 30-60 year old men follows a normal distribution with mean 26 and standard deviation 4.  If we take a random sample of 7 men age 30-60 years old. whe is the probability that the average BMI of these 7 men is equal to or larger than 30?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are fairly new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are so far; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them write their answers at an appropriate level. 

Also have a look at http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/9959/75923 and http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1803/75923

Answer (score 1):

The sample average BMI $\bar{X}$ of the $7$ people has normal distribution, mean $26$, standard deviation $\frac{4}{\sqrt{7}}$.

We want the probability that $\bar{X}\ge 30$. This is the probability that a standard normal $Z$ is $\ge \frac{30-26}{4/sqrt{7}}$. This probability can be cound using tables of the standard normal, or software.  Actually, most software will evaluate the probability that $\bar{X}\ge 30$ directly, if you enter the population mean and standard deviation, and the sample size.